# RecyclerViewAdapter which is decoubled from layout using data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I am trying to make a RecyclerViewAdapter which will be able to change between list view and grid view and I am wondering if I have to make an extra adapter with almost the same information in it.

I was wondering if it is possible to use DataBinding to make a RecyclerViewAdapter which will just take a list of events and a layout in its parameters, and then, because the layout is using data binding, then it will take care of populating itself with the necessary information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate in onCreateView as many views as you desire.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        when (viewType) {
            1 -> {
                return LoadingViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, parent, false))
            }
            2 -> return ViewHolderAds(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, parent, false))
            3 -> return ViewHolderGarage(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, parent, false))
        }
        return DefaultHolderHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, parent, false))
    }
```

Comment: Will the different view holders then inherit the Default view holder?

Comment: Also I am using viewbinding so I dont need to call R.layout.ID